# detect total amount of characters displayed in UILabel

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there a way to detect the total amount of characters displayed in an UIlabel. 
The uilabels text is from an NSString.
The uilabel is an outlet. 
Any help and example would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`yourOutletName.text.length` will give the total number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this also

```
NSString *myString=@"Sample";
NSUInteger characterCount = [myString length];
```

Comment: This works for a string, but not a label, which is what the question asks.